Is learning useEffect() becoming less crucial for data fetching in React? Should newcomers prioritise learning React Query over useEffect()?
I've been working on a React component to fetch data from the GitHub API using useEffect.
UPDATE
There is loading, error and data handled all declared with the help of useState() and then rendering the content as per the response from the API.
My instructor mentioned that we would not need useEffect() any longer (after almost spending 14 lectures on useEffect - which is a good amount of time for new learners) as it is being replaced by React Query (which the instructor will teach in many sections). This has made me curious about the future of useEffect in modern React development.
My Questions:

Is useEffect becoming less relevant for data fetching with the rise of React Query?

What does React Query bring to the table that useEffect cannot? I learned that React Query is more useful on remote data handling where a FE React application need not store the data in the component but directly the data updates happen on the server.

Are there scenarios where useEffect is still preferred or necessary despite the capabilities of React Query?

How do you decide between using useEffect and React Query in your projects?

Considering the learning curve associated with useEffect, should new learners avoid learning useEffect() and start directly with React Query instead? similar to the way we stopped  learning class based components after React-16 & instead focused on Functional components to save time and efforts.


I understand that useEffect is a general-purpose hook used for various side effects beyond data fetching, such as subscriptions, manual DOM manipulations, and more. However, I'm particularly interested in how its usage for data fetching is evolving with tools like React Query.
I appreciate any guidance on how to best leverage these tools in modern React development.
Here is my current implementation with useEffect()
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const url = "https://api.github.com/users/emmeiwhite";

const MultipleReturnsFetchData = () => {
  /** In this challenge, I want to get the github user from an API */
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [person, setPerson] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const fetchUser = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);

      // fetch gocha!
      if (!response.ok) {
        setError(true);
        setIsLoading(false);
        return;
        // we simply return in this case and our error state is true which will output the if(error) condition in the browser!
      }
      const user = await response.json();
      console.log(user);
      setPerson(user);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      setError(true);
      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUser();
  }, []);

  /** Order matters here:
 * First comes loading, then error and only then the normal JSX return from the component
   */

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading ...</h1>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <h1>There was an error ...</h1>;
  }

  const styles = {
    width: "150px",
    borderRadius: "100%",
  };

  return (
    <article>
      <img
        src={person.avatar_url}
        alt={person.login}
        style={styles}
      />
      <h1>{person.name}</h1>
      <h3>Works at {person.company}</h3>
      <p>{person.bio}</p>
    </article>
  );
};
export default MultipleReturnsFetchData;





Is useEffect becoming obsolete for data fetching with the rise of React Query?

React Query (if you mean https://tanstack.com/query/latest) is just a library and doesn't make anything obsolete. See below:

Are there scenarios where useEffect is still preferred or necessary despite the capabilities of React Query?
How do you decide between using useEffect and React Query in your projects?

There are many ways to fetch data in React, and I for one prefer swr over TanStack Query due to its simplicity.

Additionally, considering the learning curve associated with useEffect, should new learners avoid it and start with React Query instead?

It's essential to understand how useEffect works, but writing your own data fetching from scratch with it over and over tends to be a chore and easy to get wrong around the corner cases (and unnecessary, given alternatives).

I learn that React_Query is particularly best for remote data handling directly on the server as well. I have updated question a bit, consider checking :)
And please if you feel consider re-opening if required as per the updates

What makes you say that about React Query? You can do mutations with swr just as well, if you like.

I actually just got started with it, Doing a course and being a Frontend developer, here in the project I am working on the remote server which is created in node by the instructor and we are directly modifying data on server. But I will definitely consider swr once I gain more insight of the library.  I thank you a lot. Discussions and answers like these opens the doors for more learnings, Just that time management is required to learn more stuff while at work.  Added few more points in the question, see if they make sense, updated title as well. Do consider voting if it can help others :)

I accepted your answer as it is precise and future proof in general @AKX :)

useEffect is the simplest hook to implement, but using useEffect to fetch API data is not recommended for large projects. Libraries like React Query are developed to make data fetching, caching, and updating easy with clean code. React Query makes pagination, caching, and error handling straightforward. useEffect is not obsolete; in fact, React Query also uses useEffect under the hood to dispatch updates. Other expample is urql-graphql or apollo which is also developed to manage graphql API data with clean code. Libraries like React Query help to write clean code for projects.
